# Difference between isElementDisplayed vs toBeDisplayed vs isDisplayed vs waitForDisplayed in webdriverIO?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

Can anyone explain what is the difference between these during actual automation

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I have figured it out-

```
it('isElementDisplayed vs toBeDisplayed vs isDisplayed vs waitForDisplayed', () => {
    browser.url('https://www.ratvader.com/')

    //isDisplayed is used on an Element
    console.log($('#abc').isDisplayed())

    //isElementDisplayed is used on a browser
    console.log(browser.isElementDisplayed('#abc"]'))

    //toBeDisplayed is used in assertion
    expect($('#abc')).toBeDisplayed()

    //waitForDisplayed is a wait condition
    $('#abc').waitForDisplayed(6000, false, 'i have timed out', 200);
});
```